# Send Google Map Get Directions result to email from website

Tags: google-maps

I'm in need to send an email that contain Google Map get Direction's result along with direction Image.

First of all I'm not sure that it's legal to send those details in email from my website that has only facility to list Direction result on my website page.

Secondly, If its legal, is there any easy way or some Google map API to send those data in email from my website or Manipulate those Direction result to embed it in email - the same functionality on Google Map .

I can manipulate path GEO data of Google map get direction to show Static Image and include it in email but not sure its legal to show static map in email and I'm not sure about how to manipulate Direction described result like source to destination div structure.

Can anybody give suggestion/thought on the above scenario that whether it's legal or any easy implementation of such functionality?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think the terms do not allow this.

But when you only have 1 direction(it's not clear by the question) you  may create a link to google-maps which contains the direction.

Regarding to the mail-issue: I don't know any solution

Comment: Thank you Dr.Molle, appreciate your prompt reply.

Functionality to show direction result on Google Map page- redirect User to Google Map - was done previously, but I thought to show on same page to facilitate User to Google desired direction on my page  and also facilitate with other features avail on Google Map.

Comment: This will only be legal if anyone has access to the map on your page.